# RegEx character limits

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to change the RegEx below too a-Z 0-9 and underscore only

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\-][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/;
```

The 2,4 what does that mean? does that mean check the TLD is a min. of 2 to 4 char. max?

```
var emailRegex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/;
```

How would I add a required 250 char, would {250,250} at the end do it?

```
// original
      var messageRegex = 
new RegExp(/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/gim); 

// would this work?
      var messageRegex = 
new RegExp(/<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>/gim){250,250}$/;
```

Comment: Do you want exactly 250 characters?

Comment: @Josh 250 to 500 chr... should it be 250,500 ?

Comment: Posted a possible answer. Let me know if this is what you're asking :)

Comment: Retagged, I assume you're talking JS, but if you're not go ahead and slap me :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the dead horse. Email address valudation by regex is a bad idea.

Comment: @tripleee what are the other options?

Comment: Look for similar questions on StackOverflow.  If you need to be able to send mail to the guy, send a message with an activation link.  If you don't really need the email address, be very liberal in what you accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, then these should be what you're looking for:

1. Matching a set of characters within A-z, 0-9, and _.

   ```
   // Would match any input with A-z 0-9 or _ in any position, given at least one char.
   var nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z\d_]+$/;
   ```
2. You're right about the `{2,4}`. it specifies that `[\w-]` should
   match two, three, or four characters.
3. Your message RegExp will force the input to be exactly 250 characters long to get a match. If you want more than 250 and less than 500, then append `{251,500}` instead.
4. Final note, RegExp literals look like `/someRegex/ig`. If you're using a literal then there's no reason to wrap in the constructor (i.e. `new RegExp`).
5. Last note, I, personally avoid `*` in my RegExp's, since this can lead to fun bug if the star runs into the the closing slash and someone attempts to comment out the expression.

   ```
   /* Comment out some code
   var myRe = /[a-z]*/i; // The comment stops before the i.
   */ // This line breaks your code.
   ```

**Edit:** Updated point three based on OP feedback.

Comment: Do not use `[A-z]` to match upper- and lowercase letters.  It works, but it also matches the characters `[`, `]`, `^`, `_`, backslash and backtick, whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.  Use `[A-Za-z]` or the `/i` modifier instead.